React/React native state not updating
I know that this is some silly question but trust me i the state is not updating and i am unable to know why, I'm trying from hours but still its always same, below is my simple useEffect :
 const [notificationData, setNotificationData] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
        messaging().getInitialNotification().then(remoteMessage => {
          if(remoteMessage){
            console.log("this is remove message", remoteMessage)
            setNotificationData(remoteMessage?.notification.body)
          }
        })
      }, [])

Here all i need is to setNotificationData and i need that notification.body text to be showing in my View that it, but its just don't update.
Here are the things I have verified before you asked,

Is remoteMessage?.notification.body have value? Yes I am 100% it does
have, value, even if i try with static value instead of
remoteMessage?.notification.body, its still same, doesn't get
updated.

Did i tried outside the getInitialNotification promise? Yes it works perfectly fine if i setNotificationData outside the promise, when i directly set state in useEffect.


I wonder, like by any chance its due to any behaviour or  firebbase's notification promise that state changes doesn't work.

make you sure to use it in correct place, i use it in my native component (Bottom Tab Navigator)
rnfirebase Check the steps for adding and do not forget google-services.json file from console.firebase
  useEffect(() => {
const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async notification => {
  console.log('this onMessage', notification);
});
try {
  messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
    if (remoteMessage) {
      console.log('this onNotificationOpenedApp', remoteMessage);
    }
  });
  messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(remoteMessage => {
    console.log('this setBackgroundMessageHandler', remoteMessage);
  });
  messaging()
    .getInitialNotification()
    .then(remoteMessage => {
      if (remoteMessage) {
        console.log('this getInitialNotification', remoteMessage);
      }
    });
} catch (error) {
  console.log('this catch error messaging', error);
}

return unsubscribe;
}, []);

This code works for me in my projects
I hope I was useful and good luck 

You didn't got my point i guess,  the code you shared is indeed correct, but this is already working for my, where you did console.log('this getInitialNotification', remoteMessage); , its already getting logged my side, the problem is that if i call setState here, then it just don't update my state.
